# Grounding a bi polar high voltage pulser

Tags: power-electronics, high-voltage, push-pull, bipolar, power-supply

This was a "brain teaser" in a circuits class, where only theory is required. Any equations or vocabulary to look into would be greatly appreciated. The question is the following:

You are designing a high voltage pulser for use in electrochemistry. This device sends a +/-2kV (4kV peak to peak) signal that lasts for 60 nanoseconds, every 100 microseconds. The circuit has a high voltage DC power supply that sends the power to a high speed switch (push-pull circuit) (60A maximum), then sends the signal through an electroporation cuvette with a 2mm gap between electrodes. How do you ground the system? Leaving the system floating risks damaging the switch. Grounding to the common of the High voltage power supply runs the risk of causing an offset on the common line and can damage the cells in the cuvette. Grounding through the wall outlet will trip the breaker. Are there steps you can take to prevent these problems?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Start by asking yourself, and then answering, these questions: "Why does leaving the system floating risk damage to the switch?" and "Why does grounding the common risk a damaging offset?" and "Why does grounding to the wall outlet trip a breaker?" What's being implied by the puzzle question? Or are you saying that you just want someone telling you what to search for (bridging) so you can find answers on the web without understanding? Is this "hunt the theory on the web?" Or is this about demonstrating understanding of the issues?